# EclipseLink MOXy: Bind model to multiple XML locations not working

Tags: binding, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a binding from a source XML file to a model in JAXB objects. Source XML looks for example like this:

`<school>
...
</school>`

After some processing my data model is nested like e.g. this

`schoolX
  courseA
    student1
  courseB
    student1`

When I call binder.updateXml(school), even though student1 is assigned to both instances of Course in my JAXB objects, it will in the XML only be placed in courseB.

- Is this the normal behavior if student1 is assigned to multiple courses?
- When I use a cloned student1 for one of the courses everything works as expected.

My bindings look like this:

`<java-type name="School">
   <java-attributes>
      <xml-element java-attribute="courses" xml-path="course/" type="my.model.Course" container-type="java.util.List"/>
   </java-attributes>
</java-type>
<java-type name="Course">
   <java-attributes>
      <xml-element java-attribute="students" xml-path="student/" type="my.model.Student" container-type="java.util.List"/>
   </java-attributes>
</java-type>
<java-type name="Student">
   <java-attributes>
      <xml-element java-attribute="name" xml-path="@name"/>
   </java-attributes>
</java-type>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrt `Binder` a JAXB implementation considers that there is a 1-to-1 relationship between objects and nodes.  You can see this in the following methods:

- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html#getXMLNode(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html#getXMLNode%28java.lang.Object%29)
- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html#getJAXBNode(XmlNode)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html#getJAXBNode%28XmlNode%29)

This is why you are running into issues when you have the same instance in two locations.  For `Binder` a JAXB implementation expects these two instances to be different.  This requirement doesn't exist when `Marshaller` is used.